# Pika - RabbitMQ - Why is my deliver-rate greater than acknowledge rate when using prefetch-count 1 for consumer

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a problem with the RabbitMQ implementation PIKA in Python.
I want to consume 1 message from a queue, work with it and acknowledge it when the work is done. Then the next message should be received.

I used the prefetch_count = 1 option, to tell rabbitMQ that this consumer only wants 1 message at a time and don't want a new message until this message is acknowledged.

Here is my (very simple) code:

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials("username","password")
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='1.2.3.4', credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

def consume(ch, method, properties, body):
    time.sleep(5) # Here is the work, now just hold 5 seconds
    ch.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)

def init():
    channel.basic_consume(
        queue="raw.archive", on_message_callback=consume, auto_ack=False)
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
```

So my question is, why does rabbitmq deliver more documents (40/sec) than acknowledged (0.20/sec, correct, because of 5 seconds pause). Shouldn't these two be equal?
Furthermore the Unacked value (1650) should never be greater than 1, because it should not deliver any document, until this document gets acknowleged.

[image]

[image]
The second view shows, that the consumer has no prefetch count. But the prefetch count is set on the connection. Maybe I must set it to the consumer, but I don't know, how to set this.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to replace auto_ack with no_ack

Comment: Could you try moving the basic_qos set to before the basic_consume?
Seems it is needed for it to be taken into account.

Comment: Thank you very much @Oliver. That worked. That simple. I don't get it :D Can you post it as an answer, so you can get reputation for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by Marcel,

Issue is related to when the basic_qos is set on the channel.
It seems it should be set prior to the basic_consume.

```
def init():
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(
        queue="raw.archive", on_message_callback=consume, auto_ack=False)
    channel.start_consuming()
```